# Is there any obligation for a Jew to save a gentile's life?

Tags: gentiles, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Does "al taamod al dam rei'echa" refer to only Jews? Does anyone interpret it as meaning a gentile (who is not an idoloter)?

Answer (score 2):

The [Ramban](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%96)(Sefer Hamitzvos Aseh 16) writes that we are mechallel shabbos for a Ger Toshav:

**שנצטוינו להחיות גר ותושב להצילו מרעתו שאם היה נטבע בנהר או נפל עליו הגל שנטרח בכל כחנו בהצלתו ואם היה חולה נתעסק ברפואתו**, וכל שכן מאחינו ישראל או גר צדק שאנו מחוייבים לו בכל אלה **והוא בהם פקוח נפש שדוחה שבת והוא אמרו יתעלה וכי ימוך אחיך ומטה ידו עמך והחזקת בו גר ותושב וחי עמך.** ומאמרם בתלמוד גר אתה מצווה עליו להחיותו עכו"ם אין אתה מצווה מצווה עליו להחיותו. ומצוה זו מנאה בעל הלכות החיה את האח. והרב כולל אותה עם הצדקה במצות [עשה] קצ"ה מפסוק "פתוח תפתח את ידך". והם שתים מצוות באמת.
מגלת אסתר

Comment: @user6591 Yes it does. However, as that point was unsourced, that leaves the disagreement questionable.

Comment: רעיך may include Noahides.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom אמר קרא רעך רעך ולא גר תושב bava metzia 112b

Comment: אחד מפרטי ענין דרכי שלום הוא שלא לגלות שאינו הצילו או עוזרו אלא משום דרכי זשלום. וודאי כששאל בפרסום במקום שיכול לישמט מנו כמו פה במי יודע אין לענות כלל. וסיג לחכמה שתיקה. ודאי. מיהו בכה׳ג סייג לחיים שתיקה.

Comment: @user6591 shkoyach. Duly noted

Comment: @Mefareseh תזכה למצות. אמנם זה לא יתרץ הקושיא כמות שהוא. כמדומה שא׳א לתרץ זה כהוגן בהאי פורמאט. הדבר נפלא בעיני כמה אינו יהודיים באים כאן וקוראין הענינים ומבינים בטוב טעם. ולואי שיהיה אני חכם כ׳כ להבין ענינים שאיני מלומד בהם כלל כמו האי נכרים!

Comment: @user6591 גדול מצווה ועושה ממי שאינו. משום שיש בו שטן שמפריע.

Comment: @Mefaresh תנוח דעתך שהנחת דעתי:)

Comment: I have another question: Why does the pasuk have to include a ger? Why would we think otherwise when ger is included in all the mitzvot?

Comment: Good question. The mefarshim speak about it. See the Rambam deos 6:4

Comment: Sorry קיא: @Emetv'Shalom אמר קרא רעך רעך ולא גר תושב bava metzia 112b